# WordPress change post id in the permalink url

Tags: php, wordpress

I've setup following permalink structure in WordPress:

```
http://localhost/%postname%/%post_id%
```

This works great but what I need is to change the post_id in the url. So I'm looking for a way to count the post_id in the url one number up. For example when I've this url here:

```
http://localhost/test/223
```

I need to change it to:

```
http://localhost/test/224
```

but without changing the post id by itself. Is the even possible? If yes, how?

Comment: Why would you want to do that, what’s the purpose of this? _“I just want to fake the url by post_id + 1”_ - well then you would probably have to reverse that “faking” on the receiving end as well - someone somewhere has to subtract 1 from the passed post ID again, so that the post can be looked up in the database …

Comment: I need to do this because of my needs :) I know what I do mate. But what I don't know is how I can program this.

Comment: Well I guess your best bet then would be to use one of the hooks/filters that get executed in the context of permalink generation (and then hope that you have covered all with this, and that the theme or any plugins don’t have this circumvented somehow.) But, again, you will have to hook into the “receiving” end as well then, you need to catch those requests before any further processing happens, and subtract 1 from the ID you got from the URL again.

Comment: And even with that done, I would not be surprised if this would still come back to bite you one day, some little aspect overlooked, something that only happens in a specific situation or context … bam. Again, this is a Very. Bad. Idea. IMHO … even if you claim to know what you are doing …

Answer (score 1):

You have to make your mind.

Either change the link structure to use e.g. slugs (http://localhost/%postname%/%slug%) and set `slug = post_id + 1` when updating the post. Or update the post IDs

Comment: But in this case I'm changing the post id's which I don't want to. I just want to fake the url by post_id + 1. So with the slug it sounds good. How can I do this?

Comment: then change the link scheme

Comment: I've googled a bit but can't find any related tutorial.